# App crashes after running?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make a game with bouncing balls and I want to spawn a ball every 8 seconds. Currently, it doesn't move after spawning. The issue I have is that after the first ball spawns, the app crashes within the next 5 seconds. I'm not sure why this is happening. I placed             scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval() in the touchesBegan function.

```
func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(){
    Enemytimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 8, target:self, selector:#selector(GameScene.spawnEnemies), userInfo:nil, repeats:true)
}
func randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: CGFloat, secondNum: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UINT32_MAX) * abs(firstNum - secondNum) + min(firstNum, secondNum)
}

func spawnEnemies(){
    let xPos = randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: 0, secondNum:frame.width)
    let yPos = randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: 0, secondNum: frame.height)
    enemies.size = CGSize(width: 20, height:20)
    enemies.color = UIColor(red:255.0,green:0.0,blue:0.0,alpha:1.0)
    enemies.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
    enemies.position = CGPoint(x: xPos, y:yPos)
    enemies.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    self.addChild(enemies)
```

Comment: Please edit your question, and show us the crash message, so we can be of better help.

Comment: Do not use Timer, use the built in Spritekit functions,  you can find out how to do it all over the place here on SO

Comment: It crashes probably because you are trying to add `enemies` node to another parent while it already has a parent (according to you code)

Comment: Whirlwind, could you point out where that is? Where do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely running into a memory issue. I would move the scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval method out of touchesBegan. Right now, the game starts up a new timer (without starting the others) everytime the user touches the screen. Move scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval to viewDidLoad or something like startGame to ensure that it only gets called once.

Comment: but i only want the timer to begin once the user touches the screen. However, a new ball is created once the app loads now, and I want it to be created after the user touches the screen for the first time. Just for testing, I tried putting it in the viewDidLoad and it still crashed after about 5 seconds after creating the new ball. :/